# Usage of "stdbool.h" in Embedded systems

Tags: c, embedded, stdbool

I am reading about the C-coding style for embedded systems and I found the following statement:

> Do not use stdbool.h library. Use 1 or 0 for true or false
> respectively

This statement was written in the following source:
https://github.com/MaJerle/c-code-style

However, there is no explanation why to use it or any advantage/ disadvantage in adopting such style.

I would like to know if there is any advantage in using 1 or 0 instead of true or false.

Comment: Overall it seems like a mostly reasonable coding standard, though some things are clearly taken out of the blue with no rationale. The only reason I can think of why you'd want to avoid stdbool.h is backwards-compatibility with C90. But that doesn't seem to be a requirement here?

Comment: Since this is a rule of a specific project, you need to ask its developers about reasons. If you ask in general, StackOverflow is not well suited, and your question is subject to closure because it asks for opinions.

Comment: Dubious value. Inconsistent. `char a; char b; /* Wrong */`. `char a, b; /* OK */`... Then, when it comes to pointers, "_always align asterisk to type_" leading to `char* a, b;` when `b` should be a pointer. Rules, eh?

Comment: @thebusybee That stdbool.h is suitable for embedded systems isn't an opinion, it's a fact. It is one of the mandatory headers that even "freestanding" systems _must_ support, so if it isn't there, the C compiler is non-conforming.

Comment: @thebusybee I believe that my question is valid, at any moment I ask for an opinion, I understand the rules for stating a question in StackOverflow.
I am studying code style for embedded systems and found something that is not clear and I really wanted to understand if it could result in any improvement in Embedded systems since they are memory-limited

Comment: @Fe2O3 I thought the very same thing myself, with the very same argument as you make. That is a bad rule and they ought to at least explain it with a rationale, since the counter example `char* a, b;` is undeniably a common source of bugs and all veteran C programmers know as much and therefore avoids that style, rather than embracing it.

Comment: @Lundin Agree completely. And, it's not a "style" argument. It's something learned.

Comment: @Fe2O3 Also I could almost swear there's a MISRA C rule forbidding several declarations like that on a single line, but I can't find it. MISRA C explicitly being _not_ a subjective style guide, but a safe subset banning dangerous practices.

Comment: @Lundin I did not doubt the suitability of "stdbool.h" any time.

Comment: @Lundin Stopped reading that guide where it specifically grants an exception for multiple pointers in a single declaration... :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What can be said about `stdbool.h` specifically:

- It is one of the mandatory headers required to be supported by *all* C compilers, including freestanding implementations (embedded compilers). Source: ISO 9899:2018 ch.4 §6.
- It is not supported by long-since obsolete C90 ("ANSI C"). The main reason for not using the header and resorting to `1`/`0` would therefore be backwards compatibility with C90.
- Upcoming C23 makes `stdbool.h` unnecessary (but not formally deprecated yet), because in C23 `bool`, `true` and `false` are finally made proper keywords. `_Bool` is still available too.

---

Also the coding style has the following rules:

- > Comments starting with // are not allowed.

  This also suggests that C90 compatibility is required, because that's the only reason why you would not allow such comments (they were introduced in C99).
- > Do not declare variable after first executable statement

  Similarly, this is also required for C90 compatibility, which otherwise doesn't make any sense.

So I would conclude that a lot of these rules were added for C90 compatibility, or otherwise there is no making sense of them.

Answer (score 6):

> I would like to know if there is any advantage in using 1 or 0 instead of true or false.

There isn't. Using `stdbool.h` in embedded system is fine.

Note that `stdbool.h` might not be available on older compilers, but that cannot be the reason because guide you linked also recommended `stdint.h` types (which in itself is a good advice). And besides, you shouldn't be using outdated compilers.